# I want to create a depolarizing channel on IBM qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, noise

I want to replicate the depolarizing noise channel

[image]

for a 4 qubit circuit system, where p is the probability for an error.
[image]
I tried doing this:
[image]

But I get the error `WARNING: all-qubit error already exists for instruction "measure", composing with additional error.`

I have looked at [Qiskits documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/locale/de_DE/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.depolarizing_error.html) on the `depolarizing_error` function but it is not clear, or I don't understand the maths.

**Could anyone please shed more light on this?**

Edit:
I might have found a solution, but I'm not sure if my logic is right.

For my 4 qubit system, I want to apply the depolarizing channel noise to the measurement of the qubits $q_{0}$ and $q_{2}$ in the z-direction:

[image]

Edit:
I realized that the single-qubit depolarizing channel above acts separately on the two qubits:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The aim is to use Qiskits built in depolarizing quantum error channel function
$\texttt{depolarizing}$$\_$$\texttt{error(param, num_qubits, standard_gates=True)}$ to create the desired depolarizing channel. It takes the depolarization parameter $\lambda$ and number of qubits $n$ to create the depolarizing channel
$$
\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:depo-chan-qiskit}
    \varepsilon(\rho) = (1-\lambda)\rho + \lambda Tr\left[\rho\right]\frac{I}{2^{n}}
    \text{.}
\end{equation}$$

It can then be manipulated to create the single qubit depolarizing channel
$$
\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:depo-chan-1qubit}
    \varepsilon(\rho_{single-qubit}) =    
    (1-P)\rho + \frac{P}{3}\left(X\rho X + Y\rho Y + Z\rho Z\right)
    \text{.}
\end{equation}$$
This is shown by the following derivation.
For a single qubit $n=1$
$$ \frac{I}{2^{1}} = \frac{1}{4} \left(I\rho I + X\rho X + Y\rho Y + Z\rho Z\right),$$
and $Tr[\rho] = 1.$

If we then chose
$$\lambda=\frac{4^{n}P}{4^{n}-1},$$
where $P$ is the probability. At $n=1$ the depolarization paramater
$$\lambda = \frac{4P}{3}$$ and by substituting these results into $\varepsilon(\rho)$ we get that

$$
\begin{align}
    \varepsilon(\rho) &= (1-\frac{4P}{3})\rho +  
        \frac{4P}{3} \left(I\rho I + X\rho X + Y\rho Y + Z\rho Z\right)
    \frac{1}{4} \\
                      &=  \left( 1 - \frac{4P}{3} + \frac{P}{3} \right)\rho
                        + \frac{P}{3} \left(X\rho X + Y\rho Y + Z\rho Z\right) \\
                       &= (1-P)\rho + \frac{P}{3}\left(X\rho X + Y\rho Y + Z\rho Z\right)
    \text{.}
\end{align}
$$
[image]

Here is a link to my notebook explaining how it works https://github.com/MIGUEL-LO/Qiskit_depolarazation_channel/blob/master/depo_channel_using_depolarizing_error.ipynb